# If $A$ is $m$-accretive them how to show that $R(I+cA)=B$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

I am confused how to show following result ?

> Proposition: If $A$ is accretive linear operator on a Banach space $B$ , i.e. it is densely defined, and $R(I+A)=B$, then $R(I+cA)=B$ for any $c\geq 0$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I am done Thank you!